# Aesthetically pleasing antonym for "afar"?

Tags: antonyms

I'm writing an introduction for my PhD thesis. The text has to sound natural and formal, but can also have glimpses of poetry and broadness. I would like to express that a problem will be addressed from a distance and also in detail, my non-fluent English speaker mind came up with the following sentence:

"*I will develop a description from afar to close by*."

I couldn't find any other good "afar" antonyms that made the sentence sound natural and beautiful at the same time, at least in my opinion. Does "close by" fit in? What could be an alternative for "close by" or for the whole sentence?

Comment: I don't know your subject area but there is: **high-level and drilled down views**, used in IT and business. Also: overview and detailed view.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the suggestions. Just to clarify: do you think that these two sentences sound better than my original one or they are simply alternatives?

Comment: *I will describe the problem from both a bird's eye view and an insider's perspective.*

Comment: Sorry, Pedro, the sentence sounds awful. 'I will take a distant view, then focus in on the details.'

Comment: Perhaps *...starting from afar and then closing in.*

Comment: In film, I admire *sweep and detail*. In a thesis, how would you ever avoid beginning with an overiew of your concept and then proceeding to the finer points that provide your proof of concept? The reader does not need to know that I make a 'note to self' to outline my paper from big to small.

Comment: Apparently more context is needed so people don't address the idea of the sentence instead of the usage of "afar": I am using a microscopic and a macroscopic description of the system, usually we call the latter a description from a distance. The idea is ok.

Comment: If the terms 'microscopic' and 'macroscopic' are in common use in your field, then use them.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid repetition of terms...

Comment: "This study begins by taking a **broad** view of the xx in yy, before examining various aspects in detail."

Comment: Hi Pedro, Let me tell you the truth. Your two terms just do not work. :)

Comment: Microscopically and macroscopically might do the trick. Don

Comment: Hi! General requests for writing advice, just looking for improvements, are [not on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Word requests for your "afar" substitute and "close-by" substitute are great questions, but should be posted separately. You're attracting a lot of broad advice, but it will be easier to post relevant answers if the question is narrowly defined.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a bad idea to tell the reader about what you're going to tell them. I find such introductions tedious and useless.

If it does make sense in your essay, though:

I will go over [the broad points] and then explain [] in more detail.

Frankly, "A problem will be addressed from a distance and also in detail.", which is how you described it to us, sounds more fluent than "I will develop a description from afar to close by."

It's concerning that you're saying that you're trying to avoid using "microscopic" and "macroscopic" to avoid the repetition of terms. You shouldn't be describing your own writing in your writing that often. Is it really something that your reader needs to know or would they be fine if they just read it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is something that they need to know, actually it is an important point since I'm arguing that usually only the "macro" description is addressed and I do both. It's good to know that you liked "A problem will be addressed from a distance and also in detail.", maybe I will keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! Note that general writing advice is [not on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. One of the reasons all the other contributions so far have been left as comments is because they address points other than "an antonym for afar." Also, I agree that I find tell-them-what-you're-gonna-tell-them boring, but it's an established and often required part of academic writing, especially theses. The first chapter of a thesis often simply goes through and previews one by one the topics of the subsequent chapters.